# How can I avoid these kinds of memory leaks in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I have memory leak problem with my C++ code. I think this is because of pointer assignment. For example, I have several lines like this:

```
**int **p= new int *[g+2];          
for(int k=0;k<=g+1;k++){
    p[k]=new int [n_k[k]+1];
    for(int l=0;l<=n_k[k];l++){
        p[k][l]=0;
    }
}
int **temp= new int *[g+2];     
for(int k=0;k<=g+1;k++){
    temp[k]=new int [n_k[k]+1];
    for(int l=0;l<=n_k[k];l++){
        temp[k][l]=p[k][l];
    }
}
  ...
  ...
 for(int r=0; r<=g+1;r++){
delete []temp[r];
  }
  delete []temp;
  for(int r=0; r<=g+1;r++){
delete []p[r];
  }
   delete []p;
```

How can I avoid these kinds of memory leaks? I delete the pointers but I think the memory leaks are because of pointer assignments. I've used such pointer assignments several times in my code.

Comment: Step 1:  Stop using `new`.

Comment: `**int` is not legal. This should not even compile.

Comment: Gawd!!  Next question...

Answer (score 6):

> **How can I avoid these kinds of memory leaks in my C++ code?**

- Stop using `new`.
- Avoid using dynamic memory allocations at all if you can.
  If you must:
- use standard library containers like a `std::vector` or
- use **[RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)**(through smart pointers)

Comment: how can i use std::vector or RAII? can you explain more?

Comment: @saeed look at the beginner end reference section in [this list of books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).